# How to explore modules with tab completion in Jupyter?

Tags: ipython

All,

IPython’s other useful interface is the use of the Tab key for autocompletion and 
exploration of the contents of objects, modules, and namespaces.

But when I try a simple code, and run it in Jupyter.

```
L=[1, 2, 3]
L.<TAB>
```

I'm getting this **SyntaxError**:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-b214fbf1057d>", line 1
    L.<TAB>
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I totally misunderstand how to use the TAB key to or autocompletion and exploration of the contents of objects, modules, and namespaces.

Actually, I's very simple.

For example, after typed "L." and pressed TAB key. Finally, I can see a list.

Before pressed TAB key,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkfJa.png)

After pressed TAB key,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYWZ3.png)